# I have a directory1 in 02042013015 user and I want to change the ownership of he file to user19? How to do that?

Tags: linux, centos7

I have two user i.e. 02042013015 and user19 in linux OS.I have directory1 folder created by 02042013015 user but now I wanted to change the ownership of the directory1 to user19. How can I do that? I have done as shown in the screenshot below: but I am not able to access the directory1 by user19.[image]

Comment: Try https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux ... this doesn't look like a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

First you should login the 'root': 
`su -` 
then input your root's password:
`Password:`

Second use the following command, such as：
`chown user19:user19 /home/02042013015/your foldername`

Maybe it will work